# Why does Python return EOFError?

Tags: python, while-loop

**What I am to do:** Write a while loop that prints `user_num` divided by 2 until `user_num` is less than 1.

**My code:**

```
user_num = 20

while(user_num >= 1):
    print(user_num / 2)
    user_num = float(input())
```

**Error:**

> 10.0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 5, in 
>       user_num = float(input()) EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: What python is this? Python2 or Python3? (and yeah, please take a look at your indentation)

Comment: Are you using Sublime Text?

Comment: i fixed my indentation! and this is Python3

Comment: How are you running your code? Getting an EOF has to do with how the input is handled internally nothing wrong with your script.

Comment: This looks like you are redirecting and empty standard input into the program.  We need to see the command-line and what happens when you execute.

Answer (score 1):

( I am using Python 3.5.2 )

If you do not want to call input:

```
user_num = 20

while user_num>=1:
    print(user_num/2)
    user_num = user_num/2
```

Using input (in this case the process stops when the user type a number less than 1):

```
 user_num = 20

 while user_num>=1:
    print(user_num/2)
    x=float(input())
    user_num = x
```

Comment: please edit your code as such when you post an answer.

Comment: also while this might (or not) be the behavior the OP is looking for, it doesn't actually solve the question which is about the error.

Comment: I don't understand you. She is trying to prints user_num divided by 2 until user_num is less than 1 and I just show the correct way to do it.

Comment: And if the OP ever actually wants to use `input()`?

Comment: @leticia The question is not too clear and can be understood as (1) ask the user for number once and divide by 2 and print until less than 1 (I agree it is likely the expected interpretation and that your code solves it), or (2) keep asking user for number until less than one, and if greater than one then divide by 2 and print (the OP's intended code that throws an error).

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error messages by doing this (the `$` represents the shell prompt):

First create an **empty** file:

```
$ >gash.txt
```

Redirect stdin from the empty file

```
$ python gash.py < gash.txt
10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gash.py", line 5, in <module>
    user_num = float(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

So, the reason you are getting this error is because the input stream is empty.  Hitting EOF on a keyboard (CTRL+D on many systems), does not get the "when reading a line" text.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_num = 20

while user_num >= 1:
    print(user_num/2)

    user_num = user_num/2
```